# Using quotes with tr in Linux

Tags: bash, centos7, quotes, double-quotes, tr

I came across a strange bug in a Bash script. The script changes the user's input to lowercase. As the following:

```
# echo AcCCept | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
```

I resolved by adding quotes (or double quotes). The strange thing is that the exact same command that failed on system-a, worked fine on system-b.

system-a has Centos7.5.

system-b has Centos7.4.

However, the Bash and `tr` versions are the exact same on both.

Output from system-a with the problem:

```
[root@system-a ~]# echo AcCCept | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
tr: misaligned [:upper:] and/or [:lower:] construct
[root@system-a ~]#
[root@system-a ~]#
[root@system-a ~]# echo AcCCept | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
tr: misaligned [:upper:] and/or [:lower:] construct
[root@system-a ~]# echo AcCCept | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"
acccept
[root@system-a ~]# bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
[root@system-a ~]# tr --version
tr (GNU coreutils) 8.22
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jim Meyering.
[root@system-a ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
[root@system-a ~]#
```

Output from system-b - works fine:

```
echo AcCCept | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
acccept
[root@system-b ~]# echo AcCCept | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"
acccept
[root@system-b ~]# bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
[root@system-b ~]# tr --version
tr (GNU coreutils) 8.22
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jim Meyering.
[root@system-b ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
[root@system-b ~]#
```

**What is the reason that the same command failed on system-a and works fine on system-b?**

Comment: FYI, [ShellCheck's](https://ShellCheck.net) output for this script is "[SC2060](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2060): Quote parameters to tr to prevent glob expansion."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When unquoted, `[...]` is subject to [pathname expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html). If you, for example, had a file named `u` in your directory, `[:upper:]` would expand to it:

```
$ ls                     # dir is empty
$ echo [:upper:]         # [:upper:] doesn't expand to anything and gets printed as is
[:upper:]
$ touch u                # filename 'u' created
$ echo [:upper:]         # [:upper:] expands to 'u'
u
$ echo '[:upper:]'       # [:upper:] is protected by quotes and doesn't get expanded 
[:upper:]
```

---

Why is that a problem? Quoting from `man tr`:

> `tr [OPTION]... SET1 [SET2]`
>
> Only `[:lower:]` and `[:upper:]` are guaranteed to expand
>          in ascending order; **used in `SET2` while translating, they may only be used in pairs  to  specify
>          case conversion.**

This means that if you use `[:lower:]` in `SET2`, `[:upper:]` or `[:lower:]` must be used in `SET1`. You will get an error otherwise:

```
$ tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<< "TeXt"      # SET1: [:upper:] SET2: [:lower:] => OK 
text
$ tr 'u' '[:lower:]' <<< "TeXt"              # SET2: [:lower:] SET1: not [:upper:] => ERROR      
tr: misaligned [:upper:] and/or [:lower:] construct 
$ tr '[:upper:]' 'l' <<< "TeXt"              # SET1: [:upper:] SET2: l => OK             
lelt
```

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting.
I verified on my two systems that this is the exact reason for it.

Comment: Also worth knowing about the `nullglob` and `failglob` options, which cause unmatched patterns to disappear and raise an error, respectively, instead of simply being treated as literal text. Quoting ensures that `tr` receives the correct arguments *regardless* of which options are set.